# $ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} , f(x)={1\over2x+1}$

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

$$ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} , f(x)={1\over2x+1}$$
If we apply Lagrange on $[0,x]$ , $x$ $\in (0,1)$, we obtain the point $c(x) \in (0,x)$.
If $$l=\lim_{x\to 0} {c(x) \over x}$$  Then $$l= ?$$
Some help please, i have no idea, thank you!

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: To find the limit

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What does applying Lagrange mean? And what is then $c(x)$ precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a good idea to explicitly compute $c(x)$. Notice that
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{2x+1} - 1\right) = \frac{-2}{2x+1}
$$
while
$$
f'(c(x)) = \frac{-2}{(2c(x)+1)^2}
$$
Mean Value Theorem suggests that the above two values are equal, so we can solve for $c(x)$:
$$ (2c(x)+1)^2 = 2x + 1 \implies c(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2x+1} - 1}{2}
$$
Notice that this process also ensures the uniqueness of $c(x)$. Since $c(x)$ is obtained, the limit should be easy to compute.